# Best practice/way to manage Elasticsearch cluster nodes in EC2 cloud with Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudformation, ansible-playbook

I have to deploy cluster for production environment in EC2 cloud and want to be able to:

 1. Remove/Add nodes from/to cluster

 2. Assign roles to nodes (dedicated master node, data node, and client node)

What are best way to manage it:

 - use CloudFormation templates and "provisioning playbook"?

 - provision nodes manually and add their internal IP's to Ansible inventory file?

Comment: Just checking that you know what AWS provide an Elasticsearch service? Includes Kibana. We use it. We just point our Logstash output to it. Takes all the pain away. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/

Comment: Sure, we are using it in production as well, but we need elastic version 2.3, as far as I know AWS is not going to migrate to 2.3 in nearest future. That is why we have to migrate to ec2.